# How does browser knows the absolute location of stylesheet from relative path

Tags: html, css, browser, stylesheet, relative-path

I am really new to node. I was working on REST calls. I get a request from Postman(using it to check REST api calls) with a URL. I need to make a few word level changes on the contents of that URL and display the page again.

While loading the page, there is a link command in the head that is used to give links to external stylesheets/images etc but many times this link is relative.

e.g on the page with url = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/
the link command is used in line 6(of HTML source) which has a relative href source = //cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d

The actual location of this source is not url + relative. 
Sometimes its simply "https://" + relative 
while sometimes it is url + "../" + relative 
or sometimes url + "../../" + relative

So how does a browser knows this and gets the correct stylesheet/images/jss 
And what changes should I do in the href attribute of link to always get the correct stylesheet/images/jss files so as to display the page on my website as it actually was.

Answer (score 0):

NB: I may misunderstand your question completely, so bare with.

//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d is an absolute path with undefined protocol, so it will maintain the protocol of the requesting page (i.e. http/https).

Hereby "//cdn.static.net is at that moment "http://cdn.static.net"

A relative uri is written like "path/to/file.ext", where it is simply positioned after the current domain (i.e. www.mydomain.com). A relative path like "../" would grab the root dir (if any) (i.e. www.mydomain.com/path/../whatever.script => www.mydomain/whatever.script).

./ simply stands for 'current dir'.

Does this help?

Comment: So to form an absolute path from relative path , we simply add domain to the relative path?
SO for example if domain = "https://wikipedia.org" and url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey" and relative path = "/relativepath" then absolute path is domain+relative_path ?
Shouldn't it be url + relative path ?

Comment: You're right. In the case of "/my/relative/path", this would refer to DOMAIN + PATH. However, when it's "my/relative/path", this would refer to URL + PATH.